# Delete the values from particular columns and insert new values to that columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to delete the values from **Cost** & **Remaining** column from the below table and insert new values from another table. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: BigQuery doesn't support alter tables instead it supports re-writing tables

Comment: @bigbounty, how to do it?

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is you can delete the columns `Cost` and `Remaining` first then you can create it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `transactions.test_table` AS
SELECT
  * EXCEPT (Cost, Remaining)
FROM
  `transactions.test_table`;
```

The above will create the table without those 2 columns. Now you can insert the data from other table by creating the other columns.

A better way to do is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `transactions.test_table` AS
SELECT
  table1.Date, table1.Name, table2.Cost, table2. Remaining
FROM
  `transactions.test_table` table1, `transactions.other_table` table2;
```

Comment: this gives me more rows than original table

Comment: If the new columns have more rows, then this will give more rows